# View drawing order problem with pausing

Tags: android, layout, user-interface, opengl-es

I have two views(SurfaceView on top of GLSurfaceView) in a FrameLayout. I am trying to handle pause (when power or home button pressed, I have to freeze my Thread's and GLThread's), preventing recreation of my Renderer class.

PROBLEM: When I return to my app and resume, View's drawing order reverses(?). SurfaceView starts drawing under opengl view, constantly. It seems there is a bug here.

QUESTION: Is there a way to refresh contentview without recreating surfaces? If not, how can I resume a GLSurface.Renderer object saving my loaded bitmaps?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Finally found my own..
I have called `.setZOrderMediaOverlay(true);` from SurfaceView, problem fixed.